# Can someone check my proof that every positive real has a positive nth root?

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying Abbott, and this proof is based on Abbott's suggestion of using the binomial theorem. This is in chapter 1, so not very many assumptions are allowed.

Notable assumptions: Axiom of completeness, Archimedian principle, binomial theorem, induction.

My proof:

[image: My proof page 1]

[image: My proof page 2]

Edit: The reason it is so verbose is that this is a homework assignment and I need to justify every step, otherwise I will lose points.

Comment: Quite verbose. I suspect needlessly so.

Comment: I think that, because you're using the axiom of completeness, the answer gets this huge. If you would start the proof from the concepts of rings, filds and groups, it would be much staright to the point.